# Windows XP not starting up anymore (BSOD)

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios, bsod

When I tried to start my computer running Windows XP yesterday, as I turned on the screen it was stuck at the "Welcome" screen. I had to reset it. After that, I got stuck at the point where the BIOS should load the OS - I turn on the PC, the Motherboard and BIOS post message shows up, then the blinking "thing" in the top left corner shows up 2 seconds, then everything is black. After I let it run for some time in that mode, it automatically restarts.

I'm writing this here from a Ubuntu 9.10 Live CD.

- What can I do to fix this?
- How can I find out what is wrong?

I'm a programmer and okay with doing (very) advanced things in that terms, so if you know something just tell me and I'll try

Comment: If the folder is really empty, then I'd check the harddisk for possible corruption. Also, a repair-install *might* (and that's a big one) work.

Answer (score 1):

try a checkdisk first (booting from another os). Sometimes Windows Xp refuses to boot if you have a dirty disk, even in safe mode

Answer (score 0):

if you upgraded from 2000, it might be the WINNT directory iso WINDOWS

Comment: No, I haven't upgraded from 2000.

Comment: what is the filesystem FAT32 or NTFS? It might be your filesystem that is erroneous, if the harddisk isn't hardware faulty, try the checkdisk.
Alternatively get the Ultimate Boot Cd for xp from : www.ubcd4win.com. You have to make it yourself (instructions provided), because ISO download is not allowed by Microsoft anymore. (it requires a Windows XP CD).
On that site there is a link to the list of tools. If you have another running xp pc and can build over the disk of the crashed sytem, you can run the tools from there.

Comment: One of the tools is a remote registry restore wizard. You can revert the registry files to a state that was working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been updating your version of XP with the windows live updates? I ask because there have been (2 I think) updates that have BSODed computers from start up. It's some sort of problem with the patch and the fact the computers been compromised with a rootkit.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually very helpful to know the BSOD STOP number, or at least the exact text of the BSOD.

It sounds like your system has the "Automatically restart" option under Start->Control Panel->System->Startup and Recovery checked.  Try this:

- Restart your system again.
- While the BIOS is loading, start hitting the F8 key about once a second.  Ignore any beeping from the computer.
- After the BIOS completes, you should enter the NTLDR boot menu.
- Select the option "Disable automatic restart on system failure"

Then you can write down the text of the BSOD and try to get more information on what to do about it.